# How to add focus in AndroidView field

Tags: view, android-jetpack-compose, focus

How to add focus in AndroidView field

```
val focus = remember { FocusRequester() }
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().focusRequester(focus),
        factory = { context ->
        //or any other field
            Editor(context).apply {
            }
        },
    )
```